# r - How to know at which iteration a warning message is evoked

Tags: r, io, iteration, warnings

I'm doing logit regression on a pretty big database.
Basically, I have more than 600 dependent variable, and I have to perform more than 600 logit regression.
To do this I just did a simple script that loop over my dependent variable, create the glm, and extract the estimate and the p for each model.

My problem is: when the script finish running, several warnings are evoked (all of the same type, namely "fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred". I would like to know if there is a method to know at which particular iteration (and so at for which particular model) the warning occurred. I though of sending both the warning and the counter of the iteration to a file, but I don't really know hot to do that.

Any tips or suggestion is more than welcome.

Thanks

F.

Comment: If you set `options(warn=1)`, they will print as they occur. So coupled with a `message` statement indicating the current iteration, you can locate the source of the warning.

Comment: Oddly enough, I just scripted this. In my case, I used `cat` to print out the current value of the loop index. Upon crash, the highest value printed told me where the problem was.

Comment: Raise `options$warn` to 2 (which creates an error) and inspect the index. See `?options` Perhaps Richard Scriven will now undelete his answer which will then show you more detail about how to do that.

Comment: Thanks to everybody!
I solved the problem using mainly Matthew's suggestion.
I added a line in the script printing the index of the loop and set warn=1, so that now I'm able to associate the warnings with the model in which occurred.

Thanks again!